# How to solve this differential equation? (Bloch eq.)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a set of equations:
$$\frac{dM_{x}}{dt}=\omega M_{y}$$
$$\frac{dM_{y}}{dt}=\omega M_{x}$$
I solved the first one by substituting $M_{x}=M \cos(\omega t), M_{y}=M \sin(\omega t)\\$. I got the equation:
$$\frac{dM}{M}=\omega \tan(\omega t),$$ which after integration is:
$$M=M_{0} \cos(\omega t)\\$$
The solution of the second equation solved in a similar way is:
$$M=M_{0} \sin(\omega t)\\$$

I know that the final solution should be $M=M_{0} \exp(i\omega t)\\$. My question is how to get such a solution?
Everything would be perfect, if I had solutions for Mx and My and could just use the Eulers formula.

Comment: Let your ansatz be $M(x) = A \sin \omega t+ B \cos \omega t$

Comment: I need it in the exponential form.

Comment: One way to do it could be to let $S=M_x+M_y$ and $D=M_x-M_y$ and to solve: $$ \frac{dS}{dt}=\omega S \text{ and }  \frac{dD}{dt}=-\omega D $$ separately. Then find your solutions using $M_x=\frac{S+D}{2}$ and $M_y=\frac{S-D}{2}$.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there are too many inaccuracies and errors in the "resolution".

Comment: @ Yves Daoust What do you mean? Please, let your comments be constructive.

Comment: I made enough for you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{d^2M_{x}}{dt^2}=\omega \frac{dM_{y}}{dt}=\omega^2 M_{x}$$

then

$$M_x=ae^{\omega t}+be^{-\omega t}.$$

There are no imaginary exponentials in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add both equation
$$\frac{dM_{x}}{dt}+\frac {dM_y}{dt}=\omega (M_{x}+M_{y})$$
$$\frac{d(M_{x}+M_y)}{dt}=\omega (M_{x}+M_{y})$$
Solve it then 
$$\int \frac{d(M_{x}+M_y)}{(M_{x}+M_{y})}= \omega \int dt $$
$$\ln (M_{x}+M_y)=\omega t+K$$
$$(M_{x}+M_y)=Ke^{\omega t}$$
take one equation and try to solve it to get $M_x$ or $M_y$
$$\frac{dM_{x}}{dt}=\omega M_{y}$$
$$\frac{dM_{x}}{dt}=\omega (Ke^{\omega t}-M_x)$$
$$\frac{dM_{x}}{dt}+\omega M_x=\omega Ke^{\omega t}$$
$$(M_{x}e^{\omega t})'=\omega Ke^{2\omega t}$$
$$M_{x}=\omega Ke^{-\omega t}\int e^{2\omega t} dt$$
$$M_{x}=K_1e^{-\omega t}+K_2e^{\omega t} $$
$$.................$$

Comment: You can also subtract to get $M_x - M_y = Ke^{-\omega t}$

Comment: Hi @Dylan yes you're completely right...I guess there are many ways to solve this system...